# How to simulate temporary netsplit in erlang cluster from local nodes?

Tags: erlang, simulation, distributed-system

I have several nodes on local machine connected into cluster. On each node running my application with gproc as dependence. I need to test how my application will behave if temporary netsplit occur. How can I simulate temporary netsplit?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the cookie for a particular node to an incorrect value, and then manually disconnect it.  The two nodes won't be able to reconnect since the cookies don't match.

```
erlang:set_cookie(myothernode@localhost, invalid_cookie),
erlang:disconnect_node(myothernode@localhost)
```

To reconnect, set the correct cookie again and ping the node:

```
erlang:set_cookie(myothernode@localhost, erlang:get_cookie()),
pong = net_adm:ping(myothernode@localhost)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually a netsplit (or network failure in general) behaves differently than "disconnecting properly". That's why I would suggest to simulate such failures by modifying the underlying network stack.

You can use `iptables` and `tc` for such a purpose.

There are existing libraries that help you with such a setup by utilising `docker` - if that is an option, you may have a look at https://github.com/worstcase/blockade. Once set up, you can easily introduce a lot of the common network failures you have to deal with when working on distributed systems (*disclaimer*: I contributed to that library a while ago).